# Does random effects allow me to do repeated measures?

Tags: anova, matlab

I am analysing some behaviour data from several participants in Matlab. I used to do "repeated measures" in SPSS.

But is this the same as adding "subject" as a factor, and choosing it as a random effect?

i.e. my normal repeated measures data matrix x looks like this

```
                 condition A      condition B
subject 1          x(1,1)           x(1,2)
subject 2          x(2,1)           x(2,2)
...                 ...              ...
subject 7          x(7,1)           x(7,2)
```

so for Matlab, I tried

```
COND = [1 2                   SUBJ = [1 1
        1 2        and                2 2   
        ...                           ...
        1 2]                          7 7]
```

then ran

`anovan(x(:), {COND(:), SUBJ(:)}, 'random',2 )`

Now, this does not seem to give me the same results as SPSS, for repeated measures... Perhaps I have misunderstood the 'random' parameter - I thought you could construct a "repeated measures" test from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`But is this the same as adding "subject" as a factor, and choosing it as a random effect?`
Yes. These two SPSS codes gives identical results for the RM-factor "cond":

```
/*Wide data structure: cond as 2 variables*/.
glm cond_A cond_B /wsfactor= cond 2 /wsdesign= cond.

/*Long data structure: dependent var score and factor cond with 2 levels*/.
glm score by cond subject /random= subject /design= cond subject.
```

I can't speak of MATLAB.

P.S. Long data structure is like this:

```
subject cond score
1       A    1.2
1       B    0.5
2       A    3.1
2       B    1.4
3       A    0.8
3       B    1.8
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. But what about interaction terms e.g. `cond x subject`? should they included or excluded from the regression? The funny thing is matlab reports `main effect of subject p<0.00001` - do I just discard this as irrelevant, or should I somehow stop matlab from making this contrast?